# How to determine whether to save UIImage as PNG or JPEG?

Tags: ios, uiimage

Is there a quick way to determine whether a given `UIImage` object is a photo or a drawing? That is, whether it would be best to write out the object as a JPEG or PNG file?

Comment: the question is really what quality you want, can you handle always saving as a PNG to maintain the quality?

Comment: Wain is right, cannot really answer this without knowing the purpose for the final image.

Comment: My gut would say if it has a possibility of being recompressed, PNG. If not, JPG should be fine.

Comment: I was hoping of some kind of a statistical measure randomly sampled over the image would provide a *pretty good* answer. Probably some feature extractor from an image recognition algorithm could work. e.g. if the percentage of gradients is over some threshold, then it's JPEG.